# How do a library provide async methods if it is a bad practice to do Task.Run?

Tags: c#, asp.net, async-await

In this article: https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-dont-use.html , it is advised against using `Task.Run`. however there are lot of libraries that provide methods that ends with `Async` and hence I expect those methods to return a running task that I can await (which however is not necessary, since those libraries could decide to return a synchronous task).

The context is a ASP.NET application. How am I supposed to make a method running in parallel?

What I understand is that async calls are executed in parallel if they contain at least one "await" operator inside, the problem is that the innermost call, should be parallel to achieve that, and to do that I have somewhat to resort to `Task.Run`

I have also seen some examples using TaskCompletionSource, is this necessary to implement the "inner most async method" to run a method in parallel in a ASP.NET application?

Comment: Is it not possible that the async method is **not** using `Task.Run` as per https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/taskrun-etiquette-examples-using.html ?

Comment: No, you *don't* need `Task.Run` at the innermost call because frequently you'll find yourself encountering some other library method that already does async work for you. E.g. you'll hit `ExecuteReaderAsync` on a database object, or some async file system access, etc. At the bottommost layer, [there is no thread](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html), if you're doing things right.

Comment: `async` and `await`, fundamentally are *not* about creating more threads/workers. There actually about using fewer threads by not tying up threads in do-nothing-whilst-blocking activity.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an ASP.Net application we tend to value requests/s over individual response times<sup>1</sup> - certainly if we're directly trading off one versus the other. So we don't try to focus more *CPU* power at satisfying one request.

And really, focussing more CPU power at a task is what `Task.Run` is for - it's for when you have a distinct chunk of work to be done, you can't do it on the current thread (because its got its own work to do) and when you're free to use as much CPU as possible.

In ASP.Net, where async shines is when we're dealing with I/O. Nasty slow things like accessing the file system or talking to a database across the network. And wonderfully, at the lowest level, the windows I/O system is async already and we [don't have to devote a thread just to waiting for things to finish](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2013/11/there-is-no-thread.html).

So, you won't be using `Task.Run`. Instead you'll be looking for I/O related objects that expose `Async` methods. And those methods themselves will not, as above, be using `Task.Run`. What this does allow us to do is to stop using *any* threads for servicing our particular request whilst there's no work to be done, and so improve out requests/s metric.

---

<sup>1</sup>This is a generalization but single user/request ASP.Net sites are rare in my experience.